# Создание признаков из других признаков через деление. Работа с выбросами

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Создаю новые признаки через деление их друг на друга. Для производительности моделей это оказалось полезным. Модель нелинейная. Исходные признаки остаются.

В новых признаках появляются экстремумы, когда значение признака (делителя) на который делим = 0 (или около). При деление на 0 появляется `inf`

Какие есть базовые подходы к задаче обработки таких признаков?

Сейчас я использую следующие варианты замены `Inf`:

1. Добавляю небольшое значение к делителю (хорошо)
2. Заменяю все что выше 4го стд. откл. на минимальное значение 4го стд. откл. (лучше всего)
3. Просто заменяю на максимум ряда (хуже всего)

Comment: А исходные признаки в данных остаются? А модель используется сугубо линейная? Вообще вы и так всё правильно делаете - нужно пробовать разные варианты, генерить много разных признаков, а потом отбирать лучшие. На некоторых соревнованиях люди тысячами признаки генерируют и потом отбирают. Не факт, что на разных данных лучше будет один и тот же подход.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, верно, исходные признаки остаются. Модель нелинейная. Как раз ищу подходы, которые пробовать. Признаков уже 10.008

Comment: Если модель нелинейная, то вроде выбросы не должны проблем доставлять. Особенно если деревянные модели использовать, те вообще по любому значению могут лишние значения отрезать, если так полезно будет для результата. А при обучении используется кросс-валидация, валидационная выборка и т.п.?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, деревянно - экстремальная, xgboost. Кросс-валидацию  на 5 фолдах использую при подборе гипер-параметров.